# Linear-gradient en html2canvas

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando html2canvas para tomar un screen de un div que tiene un background de linear-gradient. La página que estoy desarrollando es interactiva, por lo que los colores del background cambian, sin embargo, al tomar la captura sale en blanco. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar eso?

Aquí lo normal, solo un div como target y el llamado de scripts

```
<div id="test"></div>
<section class="block-cont" id="target">
    <div class="block" id="block" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(26, 200, 192), rgb(0, 128, 0), rgb(0, 0, 255), rgb(255, 0, 0));">
    </div>
</section>
<br><br>
<p>Resultado:</p>
<br><br>
<div id="img_p"></div>

<input type="button" value="Tomar screen" onclick="capture()">
<script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

<script>
    function capture() {
        var date = new Date();
    $('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var ScreenName = date.getDate()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getFullYear()+'_'+(date.getHours())+'.'+date.getMinutes()+'.'+date.getSeconds()+'.'+date.getMilliseconds();
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    img : image,
                    name : ScreenName
                },
                beforeSend:function (){
                    $('#test').html('Espere...');
                },
                success:function(response){
                    $('#test').html('');
                    $('#img_p').attr('src', response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

En el ajax, se manda el nombre que le pondré a la imagen y la data de la imagen, y me regresa el url de la imagen guardada, esto hecho con php.
Todo va bien, puesto que he guardado las imágenes creadas sin problemas, incluso con un background normal, sin linear-gradient. El problema solo es ese... que html2canvas tome en cuenta el linear-gradient.

Comment: podrías pasar tu código para revisarlo

Comment: Aparentemente es un bug conocido de html2canvas https://jsfiddle.net/afL5ey7j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentaba, pareciera que html2canvas no sabe renderear `linear-gradient` a menos que lo hagas [con prefijos exclusivos para cada browser](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/827).

Por ejemplo este estilo renderea en blanco

```
.linearGradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: linear-gradient(red, white);
}
```

Mientras que este sí renderea bien

```
.linearGradient2 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: solid 1px black;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

[Te dejé un fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bjyaghw/)

Comment: El problema es que el color lo debo cambiar con colorpickers, al final nada de linear-gradient me funcionó. Terminé optando por meterme con canvas y fillrect. Muchas gracia por la ayuda de todas formas.